# after_commit or after_create for a model where a transaction is used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I need to create a User and send an email upon registration:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_commit :send_email, on: :create # I believe it's better than after_create
  # after_create :send_email, on: :create

  class << self
    def create_with_some_params(params)
      #....
      user.transaction do
        if user.save && some_condition
          user.category = category
          raise ActiveRecord::Rollback unless user.category.persisted?
        end  
      end

      rescue => e
        logger.error e.message
      ensure 
        [user, some_data]
      end
    end
   end

  send_email(....)
       #.....
  end
end
```

At first I used `after_create` to send an email, sending email was being performed within transaction. And pretty often a timeout occurred. So I started using `after_commit` because it's called **after** the transaction and thus the timeout won't happen due to email being slowly.

So in this case with `user.transaction do`, should I use `after_commit` instead of `after_create` to avoid transaction timeouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer `after_commit` in these scenarios because it does ensure that the entire transaction is done and committed to the DB before it 'acts'.

However, one thing you can do to help with the email slowness is add something like [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org) or [DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) (background processing) to improve app performance, especially Rails' notoriously slow mailers.

We've been using Sidekiq at work for a couple years and it's been a godsend as our app is a content delivery system!

```
MyMailer.delay.send_some_email(stuff) # this is how we can asynchronously send an email with Sidekiq
```

Using a background processor would eliminate the transaction timeouts should you either (a) want to stick with `after_create` or (b) just want to speed up mailers :)!